# Transistor not switching

Tags: arduino, transistors, home-automation

I've got a 2N3904 hooked up to a pin on a NodeMCU Board (3.3V logic).  I am trying to short the button contacts on a fan remote to trigger the speed and such, however, when I pull the base high (3.3V) or low, nothing happens.  The only way I can get the remote to send a signal is if I "manually" short the collector and the emitter.  I have attached a schematic below for reference.  I'm thinking it's the incorrect resistor value....

[image: schematic]

Comment: More detail is needed of the connections to the remote control. Do you have the NodeMCU ground and the remote control ground tied together?

Comment: You've got a low resistor value there anyway, pulling 3..4 mA out.  I wouldn't go any lower for the moment. Are you sure its not a dud transistor?

Comment: You need to do some reverse eng of the switch detection to see what is suitable, is it jus a pull-up that gets switched to ground or a keypad or something else

Comment: When trying to control an unknown circuit, it is often best to use a relay - the relay isolates the controlled circuit from the controller, and will appear as a simple switch contact to the controlled circuit.  No worries about how the NodeMCU "Ground" is related to the voltages on the fan switch.

Comment: @PeterBennett  I don't want to use relays because I want to keep the design compact and I need 5 channels of control. Using transistors allows me to squeeze the circuit inside of the existing remote housing. I'm open to any cheap, small relays you know of....

Comment: @replete I've not got the grounds both connected. When I did, the board seemed to act funky. The remote is connected to an on-board processor which has a pull-up resistor connected to it. It can be activated by shorting it to ground (the collector and emitter above). The GND on the transistor is the ground for the remote, not the NodeMCU.

Comment: @TonyM Yeah, I've tried a different transistor and several different resistor values without success....

Comment: One problem with using a transistor for this task, is that you require a common ground between the circuit driving the transistor and the circuit being switched.  A relay or opto-coupler allows the two circuits to be electrically independent, although an opto-coupler still requires some knowledge of the circuit you are controlling.  Reed relays are quite small - same size as a 16 pin DIP IC.

Comment: If the grounds are connected together, and the BJT is not broken, and the button works the way you think it does, the circuit should work. SO, you need to debug/troubleshoot. One of your assumptions is not right, or you have made a wiring mistake or something like that. You should double-checking things and measure voltages under different conditions, and maybe follow the advice people are giving you at least as a debugging step. The first thing I would do is disconnect the micro and BJT, and verify that switch terminal you are connecting to is high when open, and low when closed.

Comment: If so, good. Then I would connect the grounds, but nothing else, and see if everything still works. If not, then you have some kind of unexpected ground conduction path that is messing things up. If that is the case, you probably will not be able to use a simple transistor circuit for this. Or at least you will need to identify the ground current problem.

Comment: Ground connectins of uC and transistor and controlled equipment MUST be inter-connected . MUST. Resistor is smaller than needed and MAY load uC pin too much. 3k3 to 10k would be better. 
If you wish to maintain isolation an optocoupler can be used.

Answer (score 2):

An NPN transistor can only take the switch connection to within 0.2 volts of ground. Substitute a logic level FET with low R <sub>DS</sub>  and it should work for you.

Comment: I did have some logic level FETs on hand (specifically the FQP30N06L) but I couldn't get it to switch off.  I connected it almost the same way as the transistor, just with a different pinout.

Comment: Add a 5-10k resistor from the gate to ground. That will help ensure the FET turns off.

Comment: FET may help, but I would think the BJT should work, too. I am thinking maybe the button doesn't work the way the OP thinks it does. Maybe the button is not just shorting a pullup to ground. Maybe there is something else going on here.

Comment: It is possible that it is a scanned switch matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working by connecting both grounds together (NodeMCU and fan controller) and sending the signal to the transistor through a 4k7 resistor.